# Blue "Halo" on tabs in Safari

Tags: browser, safari, halo

I have a `issue` on tab in `safari specially`. I have create tabs and when I select any tab create border blue around it.

I think it's call HALO effect.

You can check it in attached image. I `tried to solved this` but had no success. How do I remove that `blue border` when I select a tab?

Any one have a experience in this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Safari thing, where it adds a blue border around active elements. A simple way to fix it is to add the following to the styling for your tabs:

```
outline: none;
```

Example: http://red-team-design.com/get-rid-of-safari-blue-input-outer-glow-once-and-for-all/. This article only talks about input elements, but it works for other elements too.